# Program won't display the largest number in my list

Tags: python

I am trying to display the largest number in a user inputed array. I am not allowed to use a built in sort function. Here is the code I have crafted.  As it runs it always returns the first integer in my list instead of the largest.

```
integers = []

print("Please enter a list of integers.")
print("To finish entering the integers, enter a 0 for the value.")

def floatInput():
    done = False
    while not done:
        integerIn = input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        try:
            integerIn = int(integerIn)            
        except:
            print("I was expecting an integer number, please try again...")
            integerIn = input("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        if integerIn == int("0"):
           done = True
        else:
            integers.append(integerIn)
    return integers

floatInput()

def largestNumber(array):
    maxNum = -1
    for i in array:
        if i > maxNum:
            maxNum = i
    return maxNum

def displayArray():
    print("The Maximum value is:  " + str(largestNumber(integers)))

displayArray()
```

Comment: my input is...  4, 5, 7, 2, 0

Comment: Works just fine on my machine. Prints `The Maximum value is:  7` as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `return maxNum` indented another level? That would cause the problem you're having.

Comment: the indentation on the return statement was wrong, I have fixed it and now the program works, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: this could be indentation issue. `if integerIn == int("0"):
           done = True`

Answer (score 0):

Right code for this task:

```
def float_input():
    integers = list()
    while True:
        value = int(input('Enter value (or 0 to exit): '))
        if value != 0:
            integers.append(value)
        elif value == 0:
            break

    return integers

print(max(float_input()))
```

Or, if you want to create your own `largestNumber` function use this:

```
def largest_number(lst):
    max_elem = lst[0]
    for j in lst[1:]:
        if j > max_elem:
            max_elem = j
    return max_elem

print(largest_number([1, 2, 5, 3, 4])) # print 5
```

Comment: What's the problem with his `largest_number` function that your version fixes? The only difference I can see is that yours works correctly when the list contains negative numbers.

Comment: i suggested a new version with using standart librabry function max and shorter float_input() func

Comment: How will that help anyone understand what he did wrong in the original? This is supposed to be an educational resource, not just a repository of working code.